# Pipenv: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: linux, debian, python

I install the environment with the **pipenv**. Python **3.7.4**.

---

About system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux *** 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-6 (2019-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

File `.env`

```
WORKON_HOME=/usr/local/envs
PIPENV_DEFAULT_PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.4
```

---

Log

```
Loading .env environment variables…
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.7.4) to create virtualenv…
⠋/usr/bin/python3: No module named pipenv.pew

Virtualenv location:
requirements.txt found, instead of Pipfile! Converting…
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pipenv==11.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'pipenv')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 572, in shell
    three=three, python=python, fancy=fancy, shell_args=shell_args
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2093, in do_shell
    ensure_project(three=three, python=python, validate=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 636, in ensure_project
    ensure_pipfile(validate=validate, skip_requirements=skip_requirements)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 265, in ensure_pipfile
    project.create_pipfile(python=python)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 518, in create_pipfile
    'python_version': python_version(required_python)[: len('2.7')]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

---

pipenv installed with command

```
sudo apt install python3-pipenv
```

---

I tried running with version of Python: in file `.env` and in command-line arguments - this result was repeated. 
On StaсkOverflow there is a similar question, but the solution does not suit me. I have no problems with the locale.

Comment: The error message simply means `python_version(required_python)` returned `None`. I don't know why that might happen. Can you please link to the SO question; maybe someone knows how to apply the solution to your issue.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49436922/getting-error-while-trying-to-run-this-command-pipenv-install-requests-in-ma), but the cause of the problem is obvious and does not suit me

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but maybe this helps someone stumbling over this question like me:

I was able to avoid this issue by using `python3 -m pipenv`.

In my case there was no Python 2 installed and no `python` executeable in my PATH.
To fix this, I created a simbolic link:

```
# find location of python3
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

# create link from python to python3 in the original directory
$ ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```